# CoffeeScript Function Compiling Incorrectly and Returning Early

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am writing some code in CoffeeScript, and I can't figure out how to write this in such a way that it compiles properly.

```
    f = (id) -> 
        matching = app.list.where
            id: id

        if matching.length == 0
            success = (data)->
                if not data[id]
                    alert "couldn't find id " + id
                else
                    b = new Thing data[id]
                    b.set 'id',id 
                    b.trigger 'select'

            error = ->

            app.api.request 'info','GET',success,error,
                ids: id
        else
            b = matching[0]
            b.trigger 'select'
```

is compiling to:

```
  f = function(id) {
    var matching;
    return matching = app.list.where({
      id: id
    });
  };
  if (matching.length === 0) {
    success = function(data) {
      var b;
      if (!data[id]) {
        return alert("couldn't find id " + id);
      } else {
        b = new Thing(data[id]);
        b.set('id', id);
        return b.trigger('select');
      }
    };
    error = function() {};
    app.api.request('info', 'GET', success, error, {
      ids: id
    });
  } else {
    b = matching[0];
    b.trigger('select');
  }
```

As you can see, only the assignment of `matching` is being parsed as part of `f`.

Comment: It doesn't compile like that for me... are you using the latest coffeescript? (npm update coffee-script -g)

Comment: Make sure that you're using either all tabs or all spaces to indent your code. Looks like its compiling fine using http://coffeescript.org/
Here is your code: http://goo.gl/AwGaZ

Comment: Soldier.moth, thanks!  There was a space somewhere in one of the lines that threw everything off.

Comment: tabs tabs tabs. (cue programmer mafia)

Comment: I am an evil person who lives only to annoy other developers.

Comment: Keeping same convention on your code (using all tabs or all spaces) is  the golden rule. But when you face some hardtime on your CoffeeScript code, wrap it with parenthesis and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = (id) -> 
    matching = app.list.where id: id
    if matching.length == 0
        success = (data)->
            if not data[id]
                alert "couldn't find id " + id
            else
                b = new Thing data[id]
                b.set 'id',id 
                b.trigger 'select'

        error = ->

        app.api.request 'info','GET',success,error,
            ids: id
    else
        b = matching[0]
        b.trigger 'select'
```

Comment: I just tried this on the online try coffeescript compiler, and it compiled correctly. I think the issue is probably the version of your coffeescript compiler.